# How to differentiate between servlet responses in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

In my website i am using ajax to post information to a java servlet and read the response using the following javascript code:

```
            $.ajax({
            url : 'myfirstservlet',
            async: false,
            data : {
                       //send info..
                   },

            success : function(responseText) {

                //receive response..
            }
        });
```

And in my servlet i am returning multiple responses. for example:

```
    String response1 = "response1";
    int response2 = "5";
    out.println(response1);
    out.println(response2);
```

So how do I get the values of these two different responses and put them in separate javascript variables?

e.g.

```
$var response1 = ['response1'];
$var response2 = ['response2'];
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If `out` is the responsewriter, your output would be

```
response1
5
```

One better way would be to create a JSON object instead of plain text.

```
{
    "res1":"response1",
    "res2":"5"
}
```

Comment: Json probably the write way to go so +1 But instead I have split the values with a comma and got them that way.

Comment: also a good choice, expect it would be possible for "repsonse1" to include a comma.

Comment: The first response in my case will be constant e.g. out.println("Positive," + sum); and in my javascript I have: var $split = responseText.split(',');. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to  is respond with two different data in single response. As per HTTP you cannot have two response.

You can do this either by using Json or properly delemating your data.

- If this response are simple string then go for delimation method
  Don't use ',' as delimater if the string even remotely may contain comma. Delimator with multiple carractor will do. '#Delem#'
- If the data is complicated i.e object structure with aggrigation and constitutuin then go for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think we are over-complicating this.

There is no such thing in HTTP as multiple responses to a request.  The client makes a request and the server sends back a response.  The code you showed does not send multiple responses.  It sends a single response that just has 2 pieces of interesting data in it.

Since you are using `println`, then your output is by definition line-separated. So in your client-side code, split the response on CRLF.

```
var parts = response.split(/\r?\n/);
var part1 = parts[0];
var part2 = parts[1];
```

If the data you are transferring is as simple as this and unlikely to grow, this is fine. If you want a more scalable solution, I recommend JSON.